# spring rest testing @JsonFormat annotation

Tags: spring, rest, testing

I need to test if my endpoint /people return correct json values.
I use in my Person model `@JsonFormat annotation, when I use Postman or browser it produces correct date in format "dd-MM-yyyy".

Example:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyy")
private LocalDate birthDate;
```

And output is correct in json-> `birthDate: "01-01-2000"`

But if I want to test my controller, it produces me following error:

```
Expected: is "01-01-2000"
 but: was <{year=2000, month=JANUARY, monthValue=1, dayOfMonth=1, 
 chronology={id=ISO, calendarType=iso8601}, leapYear=true, 
 dayOfWeek=SATURDAY, dayOfYear=1, era=CE}>
```

I don't know where is the problem.
My test method looks like this:

```
//given
    Person testPerson = new Person("Jan", "Kowalski", LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1),
            LocalDate.of(2005, 12, 31), "123456");
    List<Person> peopleList = Arrays.asList(testPerson);

    //when
    Mockito.when(personRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(peopleList);

    //then
    mockMvc.perform(get("/people"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$[0].birthDate", Matchers.is("01-01-2000"))));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have jackson-datatype-jsr310 dependency

Comment: @surya yes, I have

Comment: try adding @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)  to the localdate var.

Answer (score 1):

With jackson-datatype-jsr310 dependecy, actually it should automatically format , and you dont need any annotation. As you confirmed that you have that dependecy, not sure why its not giving correct format.Make sure its there in runtime classpath (clean .m2 directory :-) and believe me sometime it helps. )

Othersie you can try code as given below.

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyy")
 @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
 @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
 private LocalDate birthdate;
```